# PSN Germany to Belgium transfer

Tags: psn

I recently moved to Belgium from Germany. Is there any way I can transfer my PS Network account info and games to the European PS Store before I pay for the PS+ package? Also, would it change the PS Store language so it isn't in German anymore?

Comment: I'd recommend contacting sony support.

Answer (score 1):

No. Profiles can't be moved across regions. If you're not going to have German billing information anymore (address / payment method), then you'll need to either buy German PSN points, etc... from an online retailer to keep things consistent. Or setup a second account for the region you now live in and use that for purchases going forward.

Frankly, if you have already bought games and have trophies, etc... under your German account, just keep using that account. The devices don't care where you are and you can play local content even on a device homed to an different region. It only gets tricky if you want to buy DLC.

Comment: Uh the single market means a person is free to move around: thus this can't be the answer as it would violate the law.

Comment: Your ID is bound to the regional you registered it in. You can not change regions. You can buy from any region, but each region needs it's own PSN account, e-mail address and region specific payment method. This answer is valid. If it violates the law then go sue Sony.

Comment: You can't "sue" just like that. You can just ask them to move it and they'll be happy to oblige. There is no suing when there's a direct law involve that explicitly states that any good can be moved around freely, and no company or government may introduce barriers in the european union. Suing is for when laws are unclear.

Comment: Seriously. Point me to someplace that says Sony will allow you to move an account between regions. I've never heard of this and would like to learn more.